# SourceBuffer's appendBuffer() not appending arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, media-source

**Context:**

1.) Confirmed that the backend is returning a range of bytes using StreamingResponseBody (I'm using spring boot) via 206 response code

2.) Confirmed that the received data makes sense, I think, by comparing the logs displayed here `chrome://media-internals/` with the logs displayed when I play any YouTube video. I attached some pictures to show this.[image][image]

3.) On the frontend, byte stream gets converted into an arrayBuffer via `response.arrayBuffer()`

4.) Confirmed that the video's codec profile is `video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002a,mp4a.40.2"; profiles="mp42,mp41"` . Used mp4box (https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js) to get the codec and profile and confirmed that the browser supports this `MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002a"; profiles="mp42,mp41"')`; I'm using google chrome to test this.

**Issue:**

1.) It looks like `buffered` isn't getting updated, because it's `TimeRange` length is not changing and that `sourceBuffer.buffered.end(0)` and `sourceBuffer.buffered.start(0)` remains undefined

2.) And because of the previous issue, `<video />` doesn't play.

Using a callback `getVideoStreamResourceAPI` to receive the arrayBuffer, the following is my code

```
getVideoStreamResourceAPI(pathVariables, identityPayload, resp => {
                    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
                    videoRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
                    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen, {once: true});
    
                    function sourceOpen() {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(videoRef.current.src);
                        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002a,mp4a.40.2"; profiles="mp42,mp41"');

                        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('update', sourceBufferUpdate, { once: true });
                        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(resp);
                        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', updateEnd, { once: true });
                    }
    
                    function sourceBufferUpdate(e) {
                        console.log("updated: ", e);
                    }
    
                    function updateEnd(e) {
                        console.log("updatedEnded: ", e);
                        console.log("buffered: ", videoRef.current.buffered);
                        videoRef.current.addEventListener('playing', fetchNextSegment, { once: true });
                    }

                    function fetchNextSegment() {
                        console.log("fetching next segment");
                    }
    
                    setSpinner(null);
                });
```

**NOTE:**
`resp` contains the arrayBuffer and `fetchNextSegment()` isn't getting called.

Any suggestions, ideas, and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Hi. Do you know if your MP4 is of type **fragmented MP4** or not? MSE expects a format of fragmented MP4. Anyways... **(1)** To play an MP4 file that is loaded into a buffer then just use `createObjectURL` to create a virtual file path pointing to the Array then you can set that path as `.src` of the player and also use `.load()` before you try a first play.

Comment: **(2)** Since you can do range requests, you can use MSE by having a fragmented MP4, that means there is a **main header** that you feed first to config the MPEG decoder (settings for width, height, framerate, etc) then the rest of MP4 is chunks joined up as one long file or each chunk can be a separate file. A **chunk** just needs a correct `Header + Payload` of X-amount worth of video time) then it is playable (so it could be read from a separate file holding this chunk's bytes or else it is extracted from the middle of one large MP4 file). Put F-MP4 main header into MSE, then feed in chunks